# nosetest Ran 0 test on pandas

Tags: nosetests

I try to follow pandas documentation. Installed it on Ubuntu 10.4 but when run nose test got result 0 test

```
~$ nosetests pandas

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

It seems everything is installed correctly, so don't know what to do with it or how to interpret (I am new to nose test).
Can you help me interpret the output or advise how I should run this test

thanks

Comment: Are you running into the same issues as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385406/running-nosetests-on-module-locally-installed-with-easy-install, who was trying to test pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the *ran 0 tests* message in every directory I tried until I tried this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests$ sudo nosetests *
```

sudo was necessary to get rid of access errors on the first go round. Then I got these errors:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_cast_internals (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 9092, in test_cast_internals
    assert_frame_equal(casted, expected)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 250, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.columns.names == right.columns.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_constructor_from_items (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 2765, in test_constructor_from_items
    assert_frame_equal(recons, self.frame)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 250, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.columns.names == right.columns.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_constructor_more (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 2565, in test_constructor_more
    tm.assert_frame_equal(dm, self.frame)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 250, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.columns.names == right.columns.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_constructor_orient (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 2713, in test_constructor_orient
    assert_frame_equal(recons, expected)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 249, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.index.names == right.index.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_constructor_subclass_dict (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 2267, in test_constructor_subclass_dict
    assert_frame_equal(self.frame.sort_index(), frame)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 249, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.index.names == right.index.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_getitem_fancy_2d (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 620, in test_getitem_fancy_2d
    assert_frame_equal(ix[:, :2], f.reindex(columns=['A', 'B']))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 250, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.columns.names == right.columns.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_getitem_fancy_boolean (pandas.tests.test_frame.TestDataFrame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_frame.py", line 1106, in test_getitem_fancy_boolean
    assert_frame_equal(result, expected)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/util/testing.py", line 250, in assert_frame_equal
    assert(left.columns.names == right.columns.names)
AssertionError

======================================================================
FAIL: test_time_series_plot_color_with_empty_kwargs (pandas.tests.test_graphics.TestDataFrameGroupByPlots)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/tests/test_graphics.py", line 752, in test_time_series_plot_color_with_empty_kwargs
    self.assert_(line_colors == ['b', 'g', 'r'])
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3382 tests in 341.290s

FAILED (SKIP=46, failures=8)
```