# running nosetests on module locally installed with easy_install

Tags: python, pandas, nosetests

I can't get nosetests to test a newly installed Python pandas library. I don't have root access to this machine, so I installed pandas locally with easy_install:

```
$ easy_install --prefix=$HOME/.local pandas
... (Success) ...
$ python
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

But several attempts to run nosetests on pandas have failed:

```
$ nosetests pandas
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s
OK

$ nosetests ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tests/
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK

$ nosetests ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tests/*
...
Ran 3344 tests in 79.525s

FAILED (SKIP=52, errors=101, failures=10)
```

I'm assuming the last failure is because some of the source files can't be found by nosetests. On a different machine with a different installation (Canopy Python), I get the desired output:

```
$ nosetests pandas
...
Ran 3131 tests in 253.226s

OK (SKIP=116)
```

Is there a way to tell nosetests where both the source and test directories of a locally-installed module are?

Comment: try running `nosetests ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas` instead.  Alternatively, try running: `cd ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ && nosetests pandas`

Comment: Both of those unfortunately give an output of `Ran 0 tests in 0.001s`

Comment: If you don't have root access to a machine why not create a virtualenv and do a pip install nosetests inside the virtualenv? Then just run nose normally

Comment: Is pandas in your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, I had to run this:

```
sudo nosetests /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas /tests/*.py
```

I do not have an explanation for it, but the results is:

*Ran 4261 tests in 166.166s
OK (SKIP=42)*